# Signal Reconnect & TimeOut

Tags: signalr

I have developed a Mobile App using Xamarin Studio(C#).I used SignalR to receive push notification from the server.But its wired if start to implement reconnect & time out.

Reconnect:
NOTE:I did testing by turn off/on to my network connection.
It works well after the first disconnect(i.e;i am able to reconnect after the first disconnect from network .But again if I try to reconnect, I am not able to get any notifications from server.
I got like :Transport Timeout....Disconnection timeout...

Some sample code is really appreciated.

TimeOut:

I am able to get push notifications till 15minutes from the server,but after that the server got timed out. How to increase the timeout or how to handle timeout,will the below helps to increase timeout for the push notification?

```
_hubConnection.TransportConnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes (60);?
```

Some sample code is really appreciated.

Comment: `TransportConnectTimeout` is not what you are looking for - it is only used when the client is opening the connection the first time. (more details here: http://blog.3d-logic.com/2015/03/29/signalr-on-the-wire-an-informal-description-of-the-signalr-protocol/). Turn on logging and see what is really happening. Try using https to prevent proxies interfere with your connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm..Got a solution to implement reconnecting logic :) .. in Xamarin.mac project.No timer nothing needed.Just an network check required  before run the push notification logic.thats it :) ..

I am closing this post :)